# WCF Client From Windows 2000

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, web-services, windows-2000

I have a WCF Service hosted on IIS. This service use wsHttpBinding X509 certification authentication and all works fine. Now I need to access to this service from a Windows 2000 machine and the problem is that the Framework 2.0 does not supports wsHttpBinding authentication but only basicHttpBinding.

My questions:

- Is it possible expose two different endpoints (wsHttpBinding ssl X509 authentication and anonymous basicHttpBinding) in the SAME service (aka IIS application)?
- Is possibile to write a client application for Windows 2000 to connect to WCF service via wsHttpBinding X509 authentication (any language is accepted)

  ```
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="CertBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="False"/>
            <serviceCredentials>
              <serviceCertificate findValue="CertServices" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
              <clientCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
              </clientCertificate>
            </serviceCredentials>
          </behavior>
          <behavior name="AnonBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

    <services>
        <service name="Server.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="CertBehavior">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.112:8732/Service"/>
              <add baseAddress="https://192.168.1.112/Service"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>

          <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertBinding" contract="Server.IService1"/>
        </service>
      </services>
  ```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am already try this configuration:

```
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="basicHttpBehavior"/>
            <behavior name="certWsBehavior">
              <clientCredentials>
                <clientCertificate findValue="Services" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" /> 
                <serviceCertificate>
                  <defaultCertificate findValue="Services" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                  <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
                </serviceCertificate>
              </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <services>
          <service name="Server.Service1">
            <clear />

            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="certWsBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"  contract="Server.IService1">
            </endpoint>

            <!--endpoint address="/basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicAnonBinding" contract="Server.IService1" /-->

            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.112:8732/PcrService" />
                <add baseAddress="https://192.168.1.112/PcrService" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
```

many thanks,
Riccardo

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible expose two different endpoints (wsHttpBinding ssl X509 authentication and anonymous basicHttpBinding) in the SAME service (aka IIS application)?

Yes, you could have multiple endpoints for the same service:

```
<service name="MyApp.MyService">
    <endpoint 
        address="/ws" 
        binding="wsHttpBinding" 
        contract="MyApp.IMyService" 
    />

    <endpoint 
        address="/basic" 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        contract="MyApp.IMyService" 
    />
</service>
```

Now you could connect to the `/basic` endpoint from your Windows 2000 client.

> Is possibile to write a client application for Windows 2000 to connect
>   to WCF service via wsHttpBinding X509 authentication (any language is
>   accepted)

Yes, you could use WSE 3.0 (Web Service Extensions). It's completely deprecated now, but what can we say about Windows 2000? Take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163674.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is that I defined a 'serviceBehaviors' for all endpoint configuration (please see the code). On the contrary I have to defined a new endpoint with a no X509 authentication and no ssl encryption. How can I get this?

Comment: You should use an endpointBehavior instead of a serviceBehavior and apply the X509 certificate only to the first endpoint.

Comment: I am already trying to defined a end point behavior but it doesn't works. Can you tell me what is wrong in the new code? And how can I  set the ssl configuration in IIS? (required, accepted, ignored??)  thank you.